# OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application this is showing when i tried to link py program with a c code

Tags: python, c

```
from ctypes import *
cFile = "C:\\Users\\AMIT KUMAR\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\linkPYC\\clibrary.so"
myfun = CDLL(cFile)
```

I dont know why this is happening is my code correct if not then please give me the proper code
this is whole error shown on console  :

```
  File "C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\OneDrive\Desktop\linkPYC\untitled0.py", line 3, in <module>
    myfun = CDLL(cFile)

  File "C:\Users\AMIT KUMAR\anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Are you using 32-bit python or 64-bit python?

Comment: Does windows use .so files?  I though it was .dll.  Also, please tag this windows.

Comment: 64 bit python but I don't think it gonna change the syntax I guess...

Comment: I have tried that too